# Displaying data via user generated SQL at runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Winforms app which provides the ability for users to create their own reports.  At its simplest they design the query which gets encrypted and saved into a database.

The ability to view these reports via the web as now come upon us.

What is the best way to handle this? Ideally I want to use MVC but there will be no model or viewmodel because these queries can return data for any table across the application and so I cannot have hardcoded propeties etc. Obviously I have access to the SQL to execute it.

I wonder if tradtional ASP.Net may perform better in this scenario ie/execute the SQL and put it in a DataTable but was hoping to get some thoughts from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar situation I used ASP.NET MVC with [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net/) at the client side. I have an extension method on DataSet that returns the data in the JSON format required by DataTables.net. You will need a table/thead stub in the html that describes each column, but that could probably be generated if you parse the column names out of the SQL query or even better if you store column metadata when the user designs the report

Comment: Looks interesting. Do you mean generate the HTML header at run time? The column name issue is one of the problems as you have no idea what they are. Unfortunately this app was not designed to store column meta data. Doh!

Comment: Yes at runtime. DataTables.net just needs a thead with one column per result column, the column name could go in each th cell. You could  parse the columns from the select statement and put the column names in the th cell. You get excellent core functionality from just calling $("#mytable).dataTable(). [see this example](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html)

Comment: I guess I could have a view which is passed a model of column names parsed from the SQL. Then the DataTables makes a call to a Action to return the data via JSON however this process means duplicate DB calls although not sure how you'd get around that. I have a feeling the boss will want traditional ASP.Net, Grid -> Bind -> Job Done. AARRGGH!

Comment: Alternatively you could send the dataset as the view model and render the entire html table including data as the tbody rows. Then DataTables.net wouldn't need a second trip to the server for the data. Yes I am familiar with the "job done" anti-philosophy, fight it!

Comment: Did think about sending in the DataTable as the model and looping over columns to do the thead and the rows to do tbody but just doesn't feel right especially as I know in the future they'll want in-line editing or something similar added to it which mean I'll have to post data back to an action with a DataTable as the incoming model parameter

Comment: I have inline editing on the tables, each column can have a custom render function where you can create your control's html. As soon as the table data has been changed by the user I enable a "Submit Changes" button that sends the the changed data to a different action via a http request not a full page postback. It all works, the DataSet as the model would just be used to render the initial table. It takes a while to get into but it's all possible in DataTables.net/ASP.NET MVC and you have more control, total control in fact!

Comment: Are you sending serialized data of the row back to an action to save the data or just data that has changed? When it comes into the Action is it a FormCollection, DataRow or something else?

Comment: Just the data that has changed because not every column is editable. I keep a flag of the rows that have changed and bundle up each row in a custom delimited format, the data I send back is just numbers and amounts so I can be certain of a unique delimiter. It's just a string sent to the action. For more complicated data I would  create a javascript array of objects and then convert it to JSON to send to the server then I'd deserialize it at the server into a List<MyObject> using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe I will try and send the DataTable to the initial View and send a string/JSON back if data needs saving.

Answer (score 1):

What version of .NET will you be using? If it's 4 then you can use the new `dynamic` keyword.

As a example of this is used in the new web matrix. It takes a sql string and executes the query and the resulting object has the sql table fields as properties.

As the web matrix is built onto of the .NET platform you can use the same libraries and methods in Visual Studio.

If you don't know the properties that will be on an object you can use refection to loop around the properties in the object.

Here's a [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MicrosoftWebMatrixInContextAndDeployingYourFirstSite.aspx) that shows some of the basics.

Update:

```
var db = Database.Open("bakery");
var p = db.Query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS"); // This returns a list of products
```

Or for a single result

```
var db = Database.Open("TDL");
var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE slug = @0";
var show =  db.QuerySingle(selectQueryString, slug);
```

The first example was from the link I've already included and the second was from [here](http://blog.wekeroad.com/microsoft/someone-hit-their-head).

Update 2:

The assemblies you need are WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata%28v=vs.99%29.aspx). As I said before you will need to use reflection to find the object properties, just Google c# reflection and there are many tutorials about using it.

Comment: Could you give me a link to executing a SQL script which returns an object with dynamically created properties?

Comment: As you pointed out, the only issue I have is that I don't know what columns/properties they will have returned in the SQL